# Changing Network Settings with Blueman Bluetooth Manager (ev3dev Lego Mindstorms)

Tags: networking, 18.04, bluetooth, blueman

When trying to change the IP Adress in the Blueman Bluetooth Manager I get an error (see screenshot). It's probably something simple like a missing package I can't identify.

Use Case: changing the IP-Address is necessary to connect to a lego Mindstorms EV3 Brick via a desktop computer. The process is described on
https://www.ev3dev.org/docs/tutorials/connecting-to-the-internet-via-bluetooth/

System Details: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS / Blueman Bluetooth Manager V-2.0.5

-- Thank you

---

**Screen Shots**

*Trying to change the IP-Adress*

[image: Settings in Blueman Bluetooth Manager]

*... delivers this error message*

[image]

*ev3dev is a Debian-Linux-based operating system for the LEGO Brick*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved it. Making the above change to NAP settings you need the *ifconfig* utility from *net-tools*

To install

```
sudo apt-get install net-tools
```

Note: if that still doesn't work for you other users reported that they had to install the additional packages: net-tools, dnsmasq ([Source on github.com/ev3dev](https://github.com/ev3dev/ev3dev/issues/287))